# Spring Security 4 @PreAuthorize Http 405 POST not supported

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a problem with the spring security @PreAuthorize annotation, I have annotated the method in my Dao interface as below:

```
public interface SecurityDao {
    public List<Security> listAll();
    public List<Security> getUserbyId(String id);
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_4')")
    public void addUser(String username, byte securityLevel);
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_4')")
    public void deleteUser(String username);
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_4')")
    public void updateUser(String username, byte securityLevel);
}
```

The idea is that only ROLE_4 can add,delete or update users (via JSP POST Form), this works fine except when a user with less than ROLE_4 attempts to update a user, for instance, I get `org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported Request method 'POST' not supported`

I was expecting 403...that I can handle with a custom page.

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/EditUser", method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public ModelAndView editUser(@RequestParam
                String username, byte securityLevel, ModelMap map, boolean isNewUser) {

            if (isNewUser){
                SecDao.addUser(username, securityLevel);
            }else{
                SecDao.updateUser(username, securityLevel);
            }
                    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("userManagement");
                    String applicationVersion = applicationInformation.get("version");
                    model.addObject("version", applicationVersion);
                    List<Security> listSec = SecDao.listAll();
                    model.addObject("user", listSec);


                return model;


        }
```

My controller RequestMethod is POST to handle successful from submits (which as I said above works fine).

I have seen similar questions to this but without answers, has anyone experienced this behaviour before? Is it expected?

Thanks in advance,

Adam

Comment: try placing annotations on the implementation class.

Comment: Probably you're doing forward to a page to manage the error. When you use forward the request is the same and in this case is POST but your error page is not supporting POST only GET.